# Docker container on postgres:latest image fails to start

Tags: postgresql, docker

I recently downloaded docker (Mac OS X 10.15.4) and installed it. I followed instructions I found on the PostgreSQL site to pull postgres (latest) and run a container. Worked great. I was able to connect to it from PgAdmin4. Then I decided I wanted to restore a database from a production backup which I decided to do by mounting an additional volume where the backup existed. I couldn't start a container with the same name, and I hadn't done anything in that container, so I removed it and all volumes. I failed ever after starting a container using the same command as I'd used successfully with the additional mount. I decided to reset Docker to factory settings. After doing so, I tried again. It doesn't work. The container starts then dies immediately. I have no insight into why.

```
2020-05-06T11:41:55.463179196-04:00 container create 109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa (image=postgres, name=pg-docker)
2020-05-06T11:41:55.496823194-04:00 network connect 7c37295bd5df3fadec72496e023e329ee966f4c70544a6a6aa0c97e2fab2a903 (container=109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa, name=bridge, type=bridge)
2020-05-06T11:41:55.705673026-04:00 container start 109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa (image=postgres, name=pg-docker)
2020-05-06T11:41:55.812712608-04:00 container die 109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa (exitCode=1, image=postgres, name=pg-docker)
2020-05-06T11:41:55.888199562-04:00 network disconnect 7c37295bd5df3fadec72496e023e329ee966f4c70544a6a6aa0c97e2fab2a903 (container=109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa, name=bridge, type=bridge)
2020-05-06T11:41:55.908164483-04:00 container destroy 109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa (image=postgres, name=pg-docker)
```

I assume it has something to do with the network, but I can't tell what. I thought maybe my localhost had not let go of 5432, so I've tried changing that using -p 5435:5432, but that doesn't work either.
How can I find out what's going on?

The command I'm using to run the container is:

```
docker run --rm  --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -d -p 5432:5432 -v $HOME/Documents/video:/backup -v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data  postgres
```

This is from the Console App being reported by Docker when attempting to start the container:

```
default 11:41:55.407542-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   proxy >> HEAD /_ping
default 11:41:55.409288-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   proxy << HEAD /_ping (1.746372ms)
default 11:41:55.411046-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   proxy >> POST /v1.40/containers/create?name=pg-docker
default 11:41:55.461261-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   proxy << POST /v1.40/containers/create?name=pg-docker (50.197222ms)
default 11:41:55.462152-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   proxy >> POST /v1.40/containers/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa/wait?condition=removed
default 11:41:55.464062-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   proxy >> POST /v1.40/containers/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa/start
default 11:41:55.464859-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   proxy >> GET /containers/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa/json
default 11:41:55.465967-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   osxfsApprover.Approve([src=/Users/jboss/Documents/video,dst=/backup,option= src=/Users/jboss/docker/volumes/postgres,dst=/var/lib/postgresql/data,option=])
default 11:41:55.466197-0400    com.docker.osxfs    Volume.approve /none (paths = [/Users/jboss/Documents/video:state=default, /Users/jboss/docker/volumes/postgres:state=default])
default 11:41:55.466882-0400    com.docker.osxfs    Volume.approve /none (watches [/Users/jboss/docker/volumes/postgres -> /Users/jboss/docker/volumes/postgres (state=default), /Users/jboss/Documents/video -> /Users/jboss/Documents/video (state=default)])
default 11:41:55.466871-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   proxy << GET /containers/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa/json (2.016717ms)
default 11:41:55.467111-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   vpnkitApprover.Approve([TCP 0.0.0.0:5432])
default 11:41:55.467338-0400    com.docker.backend  external: GET /forwards/list 200 "Go-http-client/1.1" ""
default 11:41:55.467505-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   vpnkitExposer.Add(approver-1371561297748223034, [TCP 0.0.0.0:5432 -> 0.0.0.0:0])
default 11:41:55.467730-0400    com.docker.backend  adding docker-proxy-port-approver/approver-1371561297748223034 tcp forward from 0.0.0.0:5432 to 0.0.0.0:0
default 11:41:55.467873-0400    com.docker.backend  external: POST /forwards/expose/port 200 "Go-http-client/1.1" ""
default 11:41:55.468002-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   vpnkitExposer.Remove(approver-1371561297748223034)
default 11:41:55.468159-0400    com.docker.backend  external: GET /forwards/list 200 "Go-http-client/1.1" ""
default 11:41:55.468420-0400    com.docker.backend  removing docker-proxy-port-approver/approver-1371561297748223034 tcp forward from 0.0.0.0:5432 to 0.0.0.0:0
default 11:41:55.468511-0400    com.docker.backend  stopping accepting connections on docker-proxy-port-approver/approver-1371561297748223034 tcp forward from 0.0.0.0:5432 to 0.0.0.0:0
default 11:41:55.468554-0400    com.docker.backend  external: POST /forwards/unexpose/port 200 "Go-http-client/1.1" ""
default 11:41:55.472629-0400    com.docker.hyperkit [  494.229979] docker0: port 1(vetheef523c) entered blocking state
default 11:41:55.473438-0400    com.docker.hyperkit [  494.230826] docker0: port 1(vetheef523c) entered disabled state
default 11:41:55.474180-0400    com.docker.hyperkit [  494.231632] device vetheef523c entered promiscuous mode
default 11:41:55.475174-0400    com.docker.hyperkit [  494.232437] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vetheef523c: link is not ready
default 11:41:55.538427-0400    com.docker.hyperkit [  494.295944] IPVS: ftp: loaded support on port[0] = 21
default 11:41:55.559931-0400    mDNSResponder   [R757855] DNSServiceQueryRecord(11000, 0, <private>, AAAA) START PID[25818](com.docker.supe)
default 11:41:55.560089-0400    mDNSResponder   [R757856] DNSServiceQueryRecord(11000, 0, <private>, Addr) START PID[25818](com.docker.supe)
default 11:41:55.560372-0400    mDNSResponder   [R757855] DNSServiceQueryRecord(11000, 0, <private>, AAAA) STOP PID[25818](com.docker.supe)
default 11:41:55.560431-0400    mDNSResponder   [R757856] DNSServiceQueryRecord(11000, 0, <private>, Addr) STOP PID[25818](com.docker.supe)
default 11:41:55.591696-0400    mDNSResponder   [R757857] DNSServiceQueryRecord(11000, 0, <private>, Addr) START PID[25818](com.docker.supe)
default 11:41:55.591860-0400    mDNSResponder   [R757858] DNSServiceQueryRecord(11000, 0, <private>, AAAA) START PID[25818](com.docker.supe)
default 11:41:55.592174-0400    mDNSResponder   [R757857] DNSServiceQueryRecord(11000, 0, <private>, Addr) STOP PID[25818](com.docker.supe)
default 11:41:55.592269-0400    mDNSResponder   [R757858] DNSServiceQueryRecord(11000, 0, <private>, AAAA) STOP PID[25818](com.docker.supe)
default 11:41:55.629451-0400    com.docker.hyperkit [  494.387147] eth0: renamed from vethba1ca3b
default 11:41:55.641628-0400    com.docker.hyperkit [  494.399002] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vetheef523c: link becomes ready
default 11:41:55.642402-0400    com.docker.hyperkit [  494.399924] docker0: port 1(vetheef523c) entered blocking state
default 11:41:55.643290-0400    com.docker.hyperkit [  494.400731] docker0: port 1(vetheef523c) entered forwarding state
default 11:41:55.703285-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   proxy << POST /v1.40/containers/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa/start (239.215298ms)
default 11:41:55.704258-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   Cancel connection...
default 11:41:55.705234-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   proxy << POST /v1.40/containers/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa/wait?condition=removed (243.069643ms)
default 11:41:55.705255-0400    com.docker.backend  osxfsSharer.Add(109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa, [src=/Users/jboss/Documents/video,dst=/backup,option= src=/Users/jboss/docker/volumes/postgres,dst=/var/lib/postgresql/data,option=])
default 11:41:55.705529-0400    com.docker.osxfs    Volume.approve docker/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa (paths = [/Users/jboss/Documents/video:state=default, /Users/jboss/docker/volumes/postgres:state=default])
default 11:41:55.705797-0400    com.docker.backend  vpnkitExposer.Add(109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa, [TCP 0.0.0.0:5432 -> 127.0.0.1:5432])
default 11:41:55.705890-0400    com.docker.backend  adding docker-containers/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa tcp forward from 0.0.0.0:5432 to 127.0.0.1:5432
default 11:41:55.705997-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   proxy >> GET /containers/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa/json
default 11:41:55.706270-0400    com.docker.osxfs    Volume.approve docker/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa (watches [/Users/jboss/docker/volumes/postgres -> /Users/jboss/docker/volumes/postgres (state=default), /Users/jboss/Documents/video -> /Users/jboss/Documents/video (state=default)])
default 11:41:55.706309-0400    com.docker.osxfs    Volume.start docker/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa (paths = [/Users/jboss/Documents/video:state=default, /Users/jboss/docker/volumes/postgres:state=default])
default 11:41:55.706399-0400    com.docker.osxfs    callback_change_opts_if_different pin=true old_opts=state=default new_opts=state=default subtree=((node((path"")(subscribers())(opts((state Default)))(change_opts <fun>)(sub())))(children()))
default 11:41:55.707102-0400    com.docker.osxfs    callback_change_opts_if_different pin=true old_opts=state=default new_opts=state=default subtree=((node((path"")(subscribers())(opts((state Default)))(change_opts <fun>)(sub())))(children()))
default 11:41:55.707885-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   proxy << GET /containers/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa/json (1.902123ms)
default 11:41:55.810340-0400    com.docker.backend  osxfsSharer.Remove(109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa)
default 11:41:55.810483-0400    com.docker.backend  vpnkitExposer.Remove(109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa)
default 11:41:55.810596-0400    com.docker.osxfs    Volume.stop docker/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa (paths = [/Users/jboss/Documents/video:state=default, /Users/jboss/docker/volumes/postgres:state=default])
default 11:41:55.810616-0400    com.docker.backend  removing docker-containers/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa tcp forward from 0.0.0.0:5432 to 127.0.0.1:5432
default 11:41:55.810762-0400    com.docker.backend  stopping accepting connections on docker-containers/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa tcp forward from 0.0.0.0:5432 to 127.0.0.1:5432
default 11:41:55.811214-0400    com.docker.osxfs    callback_change_opts_if_different pin=false old_opts=state=default new_opts=state=default subtree=((node((path /Users/jboss/Documents/video)(subscribers((docker/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa((container docker/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa)(mount_opts((state Default)))(path_segs(Users jboss Documents video))(osxfs_state((mount((export_path /Users)(export_root /Users)(mount_path /Users)))(nodes <opaque>)(max_read 1048576)(perfstat <opaque>)(chan(<opaque>))(events true)))(node_id 4)))))(opts((state Default)))(change_opts <fun>)(sub((Watch Stopped)))))(children()))
default 11:41:55.811692-0400    com.docker.osxfs    callback_change_opts_if_different pin=false old_opts=state=default new_opts=state=default subtree=((node((path /Users/jboss/docker/volumes/postgres)(subscribers((docker/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa((container docker/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa)(mount_opts((state Default)))(path_segs(Users jboss docker volumes postgres))(osxfs_state((mount((export_path /Users)(export_root /Users)(mount_path /Users)))(nodes <opaque>)(max_read 1048576)(perfstat <opaque>)(chan(<opaque>))(events true)))(node_id 7)))))(opts((state Default)))(change_opts <fun>)(sub((Watch Stopped)))))(children()))
default 11:41:55.812771-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   proxy >> GET /containers/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa/json
default 11:41:55.823077-0400    com.docker.hyperkit [  494.580710] docker0: port 1(vetheef523c) entered disabled state
default 11:41:55.823694-0400    com.docker.hyperkit [  494.581567] vethba1ca3b: renamed from eth0
default 11:41:55.847177-0400    com.docker.hyperkit [  494.604827] docker0: port 1(vetheef523c) entered disabled state
default 11:41:55.848427-0400    com.docker.hyperkit [  494.606157] device vetheef523c left promiscuous mode
default 11:41:55.849209-0400    com.docker.hyperkit [  494.606875] docker0: port 1(vetheef523c) entered disabled state
default 11:41:55.904035-0400    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux   proxy << GET /containers/109ba7f699164a17aae50ef34d6f90a6aea86023ef7f270f8451f4b555d8f0aa/json (91.26475ms)
```

The output from docker network ls:

```
jboss@JBoss-iMac-Pro 12 % docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
7c37295bd5df        bridge              bridge              local
22776a78550b        host                host                local
47520ea94014        none                null                local
jboss@JBoss-iMac-Pro 12 %
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `docker container ps -a`, it will show you all containers. you can remove old one with `docker container rm` and then create new one.

Comment: The container does not exist. No containers exist. You can see from the output of docker events that the container starts, dies, the network is disconnected, and the container is destroyed.

Comment: I had just added it then saw your question.

Comment: make sure  $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres has correct owner, owner should be 999 or postgres

Comment: I will try your suggestion, but I can tell you that when it worked, I had just created ~/docker/volumes/postgres as user jboss and it started up fine and populated that directory with what one typically sees postgres data directory. When I removed the container I also emptied the folder of all content (and subsequently removed all volumes, and then reset Docker to factory settings).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got things to work. I removed ~/docker/volumes/postgres and recreated it. Container started right up.

Comment: FYI, you should probably use [`docker volume rm <identifier>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_rm/) instead, rather than playing with internals that way. Get a list with `docker volume ls`.

Comment: I had already removed all of the docker volumes using your method. It did not remove the physical location. This was a mount point that existed on my hard drive. The point is, once written to by a Postgres image, I could not start another image successfully on the same mount point until I removed it from my hard drive and recreated it.